# After Adding new RNAmplitudePackage(MainApplication.this)) to MainApplication.java . Build is failing

Tags: react-native, amplitude-analytics

```
    import com.sudoplz.reactnativeamplitudeanalytics.RNAmplitudeSDKPackage;

 @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
         packages.add(new RNAmplitudePackage(MainApplication.this))
          return packages;
        }
```

**MainApplication.java** . If possible can anyone share link to integrate amplitude analytics in react-native.
Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Expo](https://expo.io/) Amplitude is event tracking in build in and you should refer Expo docs.

Any other case official JS SDK has built-in React Native support. You can read more [here](https://help.amplitude.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025220532-React-Native-SDK).